# NSString drawInRect:withFont: and Core Text drawing in same Draw Rect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, core-text

I am looking to draw the string 'Hello World!' twice. Once with `NSString's` `UIStringDrawing` category method and once using Core Text. No matter what I try the Core Text version draws way to big. Does anyone have an explanation why?

The complete Implementation of the `UIView` bare bones `UIView` subclass I have created is below.

```
@implementation CTView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    NSString *helloWorld = @"Hello World!";
    UIFont *helloWorldFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];

    CGContextSaveGState(c); {
        [helloWorld drawInRect:rect
                      withFont:helloWorldFont];
    } CGContextRestoreGState(c);

    CGContextSaveGState(c); {  

        // setting up attributed string of the catagory name to draw with Core Text    
        NSMutableAttributedString *name = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"P"];
        [name setFont:helloWorldFont];
        [name setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];    

        // getting frames for the text    
        CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)name);    
        CFRelease(name);    

        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, rect);
        CTFrameRef textFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
        CGPathRelease(path);
        CFRelease(framesetter);

        // draw the text
        CTFrameDraw(textFrame, c);
        CFRelease(textFrame);        
    } CGContextRestoreGState(c);  

}

@end
```

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString` doesn't normally have `setFont:` and `setTextColor:` methods.  Did you add a category implementing those methods?  If so, show us that.